# Magento 2 Data Migration - SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I am executing a Magento Migration using version 2.1.1 of the migration tool for M2 CE version 2.1.1. I'm migrating from 1.9.2.4 CE.

```
bin/magento migrate:settings -r vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.4/config.xml
Reset the current position of migration to start from the beginning

[2016-09-14 14:48:50][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Settings Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-09-14 14:48:50][INFO][mode: settings][stage: integrity check][step: Stores Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec
[2016-09-14 14:48:50][INFO][mode: settings][stage: data migration][step: Settings Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec


  [PDOException]                                                                       
  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'created_at' in 'field list'
```

I understand that some of the additional configuration files in the Migration tool will help me exclude unwanted data or map it differently, however, the exception isn't detailed enough to offer any insight into which table may be causing the error.